# What is the difference between TransactionManager.begin() and QuarkusTransaction.begin()?

Tags: quarkus

Quarkus 2.8.0.Final introduced [QuarkusTransaction](https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction#programmatic-approach). What is the difference between

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyClass {

    @Inject
    TransactionManager tm;

    public void doSomething() throws Exception {
        tm.begin();
        // ...
        tm.commit();
    }
}
```

and

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyClass {

    public void doSomething() {
        QuarkusTransaction.begin();
         // ...
        QuarkusTransaction.commit();
     }
}
```

?

I am using the TransactionManager in a lot of my tests, and when I replaced it with QuarkusTransaction, I am getting different error messages when something fails:

When using the TransactionManager, I am getting

> javax.transaction.NotSupportedException: BaseTransaction.checkTransactionState - ARJUNA016051: thread is already associated with a transaction!

When using QuarkusTransaction, I am getting

> javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException

The Quarkus documentation does not really explain why QuarkusTransaction was introcuded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QuarkusTransaction` was introduced with [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/21115) Pull Request and the idea is to provide an easier to use Transactions API.

As can be seen in [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/2.8.2.Final/extensions/narayana-jta/deployment/src/test/java/io/quarkus/narayana/quarkus/QuarkusTransactionTest.java#L40) test, it's meant to be used when a request scope is active

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean @RequestScoped beans ?

Comment: No, it's not the same thing. A request scope is activated when a request is being handled, for example when an HTTP request is being serviced or a message read from a broker is being handled